# How to list all projects in GCP that belongs to a specific organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

gcloud allows you to list organization, folders or projects. I didn't found a option to list projects inside a organization.

Something like:

```
gcloud projects list --organization=ORG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no quick way like you mentioned with `--organization` arg, but that could be accomplished with, for example, the following UNIX-like script:

```
for project_id in $(gcloud projects list --format='value(project_id)'); do
  org_id=$(gcloud projects describe $project_id --format='value(parent.id)')
  if [ $org_id -eq $the_org_you_want_to_find_out ]; then
   echo "$org_id > $project_id"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Cloud Asset inventory. The base query is the following:

```
gcloud beta asset search-all-resources \
--asset-types=cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/Project \
--scope=organizations/920778098964
```

You can play with page size if you want to have a long list of results. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources)

I personally prefer to [export to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/exporting-to-bigquery) all the assets and then query what I want in it. Project, but also VM, firewall rules,....

Answer (score 1):

You can use gcloud:

```
gcloud projects list --filter 'parent.id=id-organization123456 AND parent.type=organization' | awk '{print $1 }' > projects.txt
```

Comment: this filter will exclude projects where the direct parent is a folder rather than a project

Answer (score 1):

Not what you asked, but if you want to filter to all projects assigned to a folder you can use `--filter='parent.id:40123456789'`:

```
$ gcloud organizations list
DISPLAY_NAME                       ID  DIRECTORY_CUSTOMER_ID
example.com  10123456789              C0123abc

$ gcloud resource-manager folders list --organization=10123456789
DISPLAY_NAME  PARENT_NAME                ID
demos         organizations/10123456789  40123456789
test          organizations/10123456789  50123456789

$ gcloud projects list --filter='parent.id:40123456789'
PROJECT_ID         NAME               PROJECT_NUMBER
demo-one           demo-one           301123456789
demo-two           demo-two           302123456789
demo-three         demo-three         303123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

You could list all the project in an organization using the following command:

```
gcloud projects list
```

The [definition of the command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/list) is:

> Lists all active projects, where the active account has Owner, Editor
>   or Viewer permissions. Projects are listed in alphabetical order by
>   project name. Projects that have been deleted or are pending deletion
>   are not included.

If you only need the project_ID, the name or the project number you could use:

```
gcloud projects list --format 'value(project_id)'
gcloud projects list --format 'value(name)'
gcloud projects list --format 'value(project_number)'
```